# How do I blind specify value into drop down list?

Tags: infopath-rules

I created a list which contain column type is Choice (menu choose from) -- Display choices by Drop-Down Menu ex. IM 2.12, IM 1.021, IM 6.012 and  allow user
'Fill-in' choices; user can freely to 'Specify your own value'.

- If user have others data that is not provided in the drop-down so they can fill-in there value on "Specify your own value" ex.  IM 5.55 then next time the drop-down list MUST have user's filled data such IM 2.12, IM 1.021, IM 6.012, IM 5.55

How can I achieve?

Comment: You achieve it the same way you've just described it ? What's the actual problem you're having ?

Comment: From your tag, I gather it has to do with InfoPath. The configuration you mention should be performed on SharePoint, and then it will work as you described.

Comment: I want to know that how I can do this.
I have one dropdown taking value from a master list. In that list one option is there other item. When user select other item. one more text box appear, Inwhich user can enter there own value.I want next time user own value will be part of master list.

Comment: I am using infopath form for this. Want to know which rule i have to apply to add user own value to master list. so next time that value will come in drop down

Answer (score 0):

Since this is related to InfoPath:

To keep it easy I would use the default controls for both operations (selecting a value or adding a new value). The combobox supports this:

> The Combo Box control allows you to either pick from a list of items
>   or type in a new item.

From [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ecf101a4-b017-43fe-9927-47921697d62d/enable-allow-fillin-choices-option-in-infopath-2010?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious)

If you do want seperate controls, I suppose you could add Rules/Actions (always forget their name in Infopath) on the control, or a seperate "Add" button, that appends the typed in option to your *master list*. For the exact details I can't help you, as it may take quite a bit of trial an error in InfoPath when in the end it seems quite easy ;).